# I can't edit my own project's cloud function on google cloud platform

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud

What is this? I can't see my own cloud function. I logged-in with owner's account. What's going on?

[image: ud function]

Comment: How has the function  been  deployed?

Comment: It also says `You don't have permission to read the archive`, do you think this could be the reason?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Tbh I deployed it a long time ago, I forgot the exact way I did but I did it using VS code terminal lol.

Comment: Why don't I have permission to read the archive? I'm logged-in with owners account

Comment: Did you perform Google Cloud Storage cleanup?

Comment: Edit your question and include this command and the output: `gcloud functions describe <REPLACE_WITH_FUNCTION_NAME>`. The output will include the key `sourceUploadUrl` which is where your code is located.